# Ajuda com entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá pessoal eu tenho o sequinte select, que faz junção de 3 tabelas. Esse select funciona no banco.
Eu gostaria de fazer este mesmo select usando Entity com asp.net mvc. Mas eu não tenho idéia de como fazer. Alguma sugestão?
Eu quero retornar o nome da cidade de origem e de destino. Na tabela sis_frete_Condição tem os id dela, na minha view só está retornando os ids

```sql
select FC.*, 
SUO.Sigla as 'UF_Origem' , SD.Nome as 'Cidade_Origem', SUD.Sigla as 'UF_Destino', SC.Nome as 'Cidade_Destino'  
from SIS_Frete_Condicao FC 
inner join SORTER_Cidade SC
on FC.ID_Cidade_Origem = SC.ID
Inner join SORTER_UF SUO
ON FC.ID_UF_Origem = SUO.ID
left join SORTER_Cidade SD
on FC.ID_Cidade_Destino = SD.ID
left join SORTER_UF SUD
on FC.ID_UF_Destino = SUD.ID
```